# Convolution with Gaussian question

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, fourier-analysis

Let $K_\epsilon(x):=\dfrac{e^{-x^2/\epsilon^2}}{\epsilon\sqrt\pi}$ for $x\in \mathbb{R}$, $\epsilon>0$.

Let $f\in L^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ where $f$ is of bounded variation on any interval $[a,b]$.

Prove that $$\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+} f*K_\epsilon(0)=\dfrac{f(0^+)+f(0^-)}{2}.$$

---

I am stuck on this question...

My attempts include finding that $$f*K_\epsilon(0)=\int f(\tau)K_\epsilon(-\tau)\,d\tau\ \ \  (?)$$ and using Jordan decomposition to write $f=g-h$ the difference of two non-decreasing functions. Then I am not sure of the way to proceed.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is true assuming just that $f$ is bounded and has one-sided limits at the origin. The simplest proof is by a cheap trick: A change of variables shows that $$f*K_\epsilon(0)=\int f(\epsilon t)K_1(-t)\,dt.$$Now apply dominated convergence...

Comment: Thanks. I get the part about using the dominating function $g=\|f\|_\infty K_1(t)$ which is integrable since it is a constant multiple of the Gaussian integral. However, applying the limit $\epsilon\to 0^+$ leads to $\int f(0^+)\frac{e^{-t^2}}{\sqrt \pi}\,dt=f(0^+)$ which is different from the answer? Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: Also can you elaborate a little more on how to use dominated convergence theorem? Thanks. Do we have to change $\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}$ to $\lim_{n\to\infty}$ via $\epsilon=1/n$?

Comment: No, you're overlooking something, $\lim_{\epsilon\to0^+}f(\epsilon t)$ is equal to $f(0^+)$ for _some_ values of $t$ and equals something else for other values of $t$...

Comment: Ah I see, negative $t$... But why is taking the limit inside $f$ justified, since we don't have that $f$ is continuous? I mean how to justify $\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}f(\epsilon t)=f(\lim \epsilon t)$?

Comment: ??? It's not true that $\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}f(\epsilon t)=f(\lim\epsilon t)$. Nobody said it was. That would say $\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}f(\epsilon t)=f(0)$, which is not true. We're given that $f$ has bounded variation, hence it does have one-sided limits at the origin.