# Limit of the integral of $f(\epsilon t) g(t)$ as $\epsilon\to 0$, when $f$ has bounded variation

Tags: real-analysis, integration, bounded-variation

I am needing such a "result", which I do not know if it is true, for another question, [Convolution with Gaussian question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1834618).

Let $f\in L^\infty(\mathbb R)$ be of bounded variation on any interval $[a,b]$. Let $g$ be integrable such that $\int g=1$. Then $$\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\int f(\epsilon t) g(t)\,dt=\frac{f(0^+)+f(0^-)}{2}.$$

Is this theorem true? If so how do we prove it?

Comment: I think you mean limit outside of integral; it doesn't make much sense as written.

Comment: I think inside or outside is the same due to dominated convergence theorem, with dominating function $|f|_\infty g$?

Comment: You don't have convergence a.e. to apply DCT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not so. For example, let $$g(x)=\begin{cases}1,\quad & x\in [0,1] \\ 0,\quad & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
Then 
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(\epsilon t)g(t)\,dt = \int_{0}^1 f(\epsilon t)\,dt \to f(0^+)
$$
The correct statement is: let $A= \int_{-\infty}^0 g$, $ B=\int_0^\infty g$; then
$$
\lim_{\epsilon\to0^+}\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(\epsilon t)g(t)\,dt = Af(0^-)+Bf(0^+) 
$$
To prove this, deal with the positive and negative half-lines separately. Further, for each of them split integration according to the size of $t$.

Given $\delta>0$, for sufficiently large $M$, 
$$
\left|\int_0^M (f(\epsilon t)-f(0^+)) g(t)\,dt\right| < \delta 
$$
because the first factor is bounded and the second has small integral.

Also, 
$$
\int_0^M (f(\epsilon t)-f(0^+)) g(t)\,dt \to 0\quad \text{as } \ \epsilon\to 0^+
$$
because the first factor tends to zero uniformly. Thus,
$$
\int_0^\infty  f(\epsilon t) g(t)\,dt \to Af(0^+)$$